# ActionListener differences between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox. I add a ActionListener using the following code:

```
addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                textComboActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
```

This is what it looks like when it is first displayed. It has a couple options in it.
[image]

You will notice that Basic Text Box is the first element, and so it will be the element that shows when the JComboBox is first displayed.

If you click on the JComboBox, you will see the options that are available under it.

[image]

However, if I select "Basic Text Box" it will not cause the ActionEvent to fire. It has something to do with it being the first element in the list. If I select any other JComboBox, then the ActionEvent is fired.

EDIT: On Linux, say you select an element, and the event fires. Then you select that element again, it will not fire the second time. It is not isolated to just the first element. It has to do with selecting the already selected element twice.

This behavior only happens on Linux. On Windows, the Event fires not matter which element I click on, even the first. Any ideas on why this would be? Does behavior like this vary from JVM to JVM?

Thanks

Comment: What Look & Feel do you have on each platform?

Comment: What is the behavior when you select the element that is already selected?  I suspect that linux is not allowing nothing to be selected, but windows is allowing nothing to be selected however it shows the first element as selected.

Comment: @Jacob Tomaw On Linux, if you select again the element that was previous selected, you see the same behavior. The Event will not fire. On Windows, it fires the event again as expected.

Comment: @user: Try forcing the same Look & Feel on both platforms. Or is that already the case?

Comment: @EboMike Yes it is Nimbus on both. I do believe that it is OpenJDK on Linux. I didnt know if that might have some kind of effect.

Comment: At the time of adding the contents to the combobox do you have a listener attached?

Answer (score 2):

First, I think the correct listener to use is `ItemListener` (instead of an `ActionListener`).

As you state in your comment this gives you consistent behavior across platforms: you don't get an event at all when the already selected item is "re-selected". This is exactly how an ItemListener is supposed to work according to the [JavaDocs](http://file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.14/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItemListener%28java.awt.event.ItemListener%29):

> aListener will receive one or two
>   ItemEvents when the selected item
>   **changes**.

When you select the same value that's already selected, obviously you don't *change* the value, so no event is fired. However, that's not quite what you want apparently. As an alternative, I suggest displaying the JComboBox without a preselected item:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);
```

I don't know if that's possible for your application but this way you'll definitely get an event whenever an actual value is selected. (It also makes more sense from a usability point of view, I think, because why would a non-expert click on a combo box to select the value that's already selected?)

Comment: No, this didnt work. I switched it to the ItemListener. I then tried it on windows. It now exhibits the same behavior I see on Linux. In images above, If I boot the program up, and the first thing I do is click on "Basic Text Box" the event will not fire.

Comment: Perhaps you could just not have an initially selected value in your combo box? I've changed the text of my answer accordingly...